# vue 3 and axios returns error with overload

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

Currently using vue 3/ vite/ axios / typescript.  My function works in dev.  In my IDE it returns an error in the ide and during build though.

```
get count() {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/info/count",
        headers: authHeader(),
      })
        .then((response) => {
        this.count = response.data.status;
      });
    },
```

Error in IDE Pycharm

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(config: AxiosRequestConfig<any>): AxiosPromise<any>', gave the following error.     Argument of type '{ method: "get"; url: string; headers: { Authorization: string; } | { Authorization?: undefined; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'.       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'headers' does not exist in type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any>): AxiosPromise<any>', gave the following error.     Argument of type '{ method: string; url: string; headers: { Authorization: string; } | { Authorization?: undefined; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string
```

Values in AuthHeader()

```
export default function authHeader () {
   
        let user_token = localStorage.getItem('auth_user')
        let auth_token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token')

        if (user_token && auth_token) {
            return { 'Authorization': 'bearer ' + auth_token };
        } else {
            return {};
        }
}
```

Comment: can you show the return value of authHeader(). It seems you are adding unknown key in header object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: Shouldn't be `Bearer` instead of `bearer`?

Comment: that part works with the api.  just getting error in pycharm/build :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `authHeader()` is `{ Authorization: string; } | { Authorization?: undefined; }` because of the function's returned values:

```js
export default function authHeader () {
  ⋮
  if (user_token && auth_token) {
    return { 'Authorization': 'bearer ' + auth_token }; //  type is { Authorization: string; }
  } else {
    return {}; //  type is { Authorization?: undefined; }
  }
}
```

But Axios's `headers` option expects a `Record<string, string>`, so one way to solve the problem is to specify that as the return type of the function above:

```js
                                           
export default function authHeader (): Record<string, string> {
  ⋮
}
```

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/NnKddm)